# Data-src / images in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have problem with displaying images in my slideshow. I basically cut index page to pieces and put them in var's and I want to use react-routing to make it work. And it does (sort of)

I have section with Slides - everything is fine except that images are not displaying. (Just images - text works just fine)

```
    var Slides = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row wrap">
              <div class="col-md-12 gallery"> 
                  <div class="camera_wrap camera_white_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                    <img src="images/slides/blank.gif"/>
                      <div class="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Great cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div class="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Fast cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div class="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>Super cars</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-thumb="" data-src="images/slides/blank.gif">
                      <div class="img-responsive camera_caption fadeFromBottom">
                        <h2>We have it all!</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return (


        <div id="home">
          <div class="headerLine">
            <div id="menuF" class="default">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                  <Logo />
                  <Header />

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <Slides />

            </div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 cBusiness">

                  {this.props.children}

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
  }
});
```

I am guessing because I am new to react (and to javascript) I might not know of some way of transforming this DIV to JS code.

Comment: This is not valid jsx.  For one, `class` should be `className`.  The attributes with `-` will also not work AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, like I thought - something that I didn't know about JSX. Post answer so I can accept it.